# AWS authentication in Locust.io python

Tags: python, api, load-testing, locust

How to provide AWS authentication credentials in Locust.io for load testing API's? Currently API is getting failed due to missing credentials.

e.g. Authentication includes Access Key, Secret Key and Session token

```
import time
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task(3)
    def view_items(self):
        for item_id in range(10):
            self.client.get(f"/item?id={item_id}", name="/item")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just authenticate as you would ”normally” do in any other python/`requests` program (e.g using https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth), and pass the auth token.

```
auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key='YOURKEY',
              aws_secret_access_key='YOURSECRET',
              aws_host='search-service-foobar.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com',
              aws_region='us-east-1',
              aws_service='es')

...

    self.client.get('http://my-service.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', auth=auth)
```

Note: `aws-requests-auth` is just the first thing I found when googling, you can use any library. The important thing is how you pass the auth information into `requests`. Here’s the documentation for that: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#authentication